# 'module not found error' -pbixrefresher utility

Tags: python

I properly installed pbixrefresher from https://github.com/dubravcik/pbixrefresher-python

I get modulenotfound with pbixrefresher.pbixrefresher. Pbixrefresher.exe is installed. I've tried to troubleshoot and research a solution but cannot figure this out. Any help is appreciated!!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pbixrefresher-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pbixrefresher==0.1.8', 'console_scripts', 'pbixrefresher')()
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 490, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2862, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2462, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2468, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pbixrefresher.pbixrefresher'
```

Answer (score 2):

New versions of module(since November 2019) doesn't work correctly. Try to use version older November 2019 using a suitable python version, it should work.